# Filter JSON GraphQL data with javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, graphql

I have some data pulled through the GraphQL API and stringified in JSON. It looks like this

```
var data = {
"data": {
    "shop": {
        "products": {
            "edges": [{
                    "node": {
                        "title": "Green Silk T-Shirt",
                        "material": {
                            "value": "Silk"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "title": "Red Silk T-Shirt",
                        "material": {
                            "value": "Silk"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "title": "Blue Cotton T Shirt",
                        "material": {
                            "value": "Cotton"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "title": "Red Cotton T-Shirt",
                        "material": {
                            "value": "Cotton"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node": {
                        "title": "Pink Cotton T-Shirt",
                        "material": {
                            "value": "Cotton"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

I also have 2  elements like so:

```
<div id="cotton"></div>
<div id="silk"></div>
```

I wish to use javascript (or JQuery) to loop through the JSON data and show the title of every node with a material value of "Silk" in the  with the ID of silk and similarly for "cotton".

I understand that I can achieve this with the filter function, but I'm having issues grabbing values of one branch on the basis of the values of a lower branch.

Is it therefore possible to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use map for this since you dont want to return filtered nodes, but instead return the titles of each

```
var nodes = data.data.shop.products.edges;

var silks = nodes.map(node => {
    if node.material.value === 'Silk':
        return node.title
})

var cotton = nodes.map(node => {
    if node.material.value === 'Cotton':
        return node.title
})
```

Comment: I'm a javascript noobie so please forgive what may be a simple question - but I'm getting an error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the line where the filtration criteria is specified, in this case 'Silk'.